# How to achieve this drawable using xml in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

[image: I want the line attached to the left to be curved]

I can get the line but it is not curved and using corner radius is not working for the below

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape = "rectangle">
            <solid android:color = "#F7B500"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left = "4dp">
        <shape android:shape = "rectangle">
            <solid android:color = "#FFF8E7"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape = "rectangle">
            <solid android:color = "#FFF8E7"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="left">
        <shape android:shape = "rectangle">
            <solid android:color = "#F7B500"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <size android:width="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#AA00FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="left">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#F7B500" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <size android:width="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```